# When consuming a web service, how do I know the type of the data being returned via JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have no previous experience with JSON or using web services, however I'm trying to consume a web service that returns meteorological information.

[Here's the documentation](http://openweathermap.org/current) on the API that I'm trying to use.

This API gives me data serialized with JSON. I did some reading into JSON, and from what I understand, the best way to access this serialized data after I download it would be to de-serialize it into an object with matching properties and types. Did I get this part right? I don't understand however in this case how am I supposed to accurately know the types of the data returned via JSON.

In the API that I mentioned before I got this example of a response from the API in JSON:

```
{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}
```

What I did was, on Visual Studio I used the "Paste Special" > "Paste as JSON classes" option, which created these  classes for me:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public float temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public float temp_min { get; set; }
    public float temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public float speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
    public int _3h { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public float message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I request data using the HttpClient, when I try to de-serialize the response I get I few errors regarding mismatching data types, like for example, float data being assign to properties of the type int.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync("weather?q=London,uk&appid=010101010101010101101");
Rootobject currentWeather = new Rootobject();
currentWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
MessageBox.Show(currentWeather.name);
```

I understand that in this case I could change the types of the properties in my classes to match what is being returned by the API, however that doesn't feel right to me, mainly because seems like it could be a source of troubles and unpredictable behavior. Am I doing this right? Maybe I'm missing something in the API documentation, shouldn't they provide the type of the data being returned?

Comment: Visual studio doesn't know anything about that service. It cannot understand, whether "10" is int or float or even string. It should be described in documentation of that service and you have to change generated model according that docs.

Comment: "Paste as Json classes" can't do miracles. If in your json, for example humidity has an int value, Visual studio has no way to tell that it could be a doble or a float. You should change it by hand

Comment: I understand this limitation with "Paste as Json classes", that's probably what make me ask this question. So if Visual Studio can't do magic, and there's no other way to know exactly what types the API developers had in mind, am I right to assume that the problem is in the documentation? Because working with this API made think that I have not understand JSON, how to use it and that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct : *De-serialize it into an object with matching properties and types.*

First check the API documentation for the types, and if that is not comprehensiive enough I would consider changing your types to match what you infer from the JSON.

A value of 289.9 is a float.

A value of 1435650870 can be stored an int.

A value of AU can be a string/enum.

**Edit:**
I checked the API documentation you linked to and don't see anywhere were it explicitly states the types of data returned.

**Edit 2:**
Answering your question more directly, *"how am I supposed to accurately know the types of the data returned via JSON?"* (thanks @CodeCaster), without finding that information in documentation I don't think you can.

But I feel you can get 99.999% close by just looking at historical data returned.

Answer (score 0):

If it is satisfied for you to use **dynamic** you can try this snippet

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync("weather?q=London,uk&appid=010101010101010101101");
dynamic currentWeather= JObject.Parse(json);
MessageBox.Show(currentWeather.name);
```

You will find more details in [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)

Comment: Using `dynamic` is not the answer if your problem is _"how am I supposed to accurately know the types of the data returned via JSON?"_, because you'll still need to "dot into" the dynamic object.

Comment: That's true if you need to know the types of data, but I understand that arthur needs to parse json and display data, so using `dynamic` he will be able to do it without knowlage about data type.

Comment: At some point, you're going to have to actually do something useful with data. Using `dynamic` isn't a solution, at some point you'll have to know if something is a string, DateTime, int, float, ...

Comment: I totally agree with you. I just proposed `dynamic` as a alternative solution making assumption that data type is not needed to parse json response, especially when API documentation doesn't specify exact types.